# How can I get 1024 x 1024 samples, instead of 128 x 128?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Good day, I have been playing with this code for a week now: https://github.com/gsurma/face_generator. However, I am using my own 415 images (@256x256) database and it worked relatively well at 400 epochs producing 128x128 samples. I tried to use another database of 1024x1024 but I run out of GPU memory. 
My issue is that, since I cannot use a 1024x1024 database because I run out of memory, I would like to at least produce 256x256 samples when the model is trained. 
If you noticed, on line 304 (Hyperparameters) I have set `IMAGE_SIZE = 256`, but still the sample output by the code is only 128x128. How can I get samples more than 128x128?

I have tried to change `IMAGE_SIZE` to `256`, but still get output samples of 128px.

```
    # Hyperparameters
    IMAGE_SIZE = 256
    NOISE_SIZE = 100
    LR_D = 0.00004
    LR_G = 0.0002
    BATCH_SIZE = 64
    EPOCH = 0 # Non-zero only if we are resuming training with model checkpoint
    EPOCHS = 400 #EPOCH + number of epochs to perform
    BETA1 = 0.5
    WEIGHT_INIT_STDDEV = 0.02
    EPSILON = 0.00005
    SAMPLES_TO_SHOW = 5

    # Data
    BASE_PATH = "C:/Users/FaceGen/code/"
    DATASET_LIST_PATH = BASE_PATH + "ImageNames.txt"
    INPUT_DATA_DIR = BASE_PATH + "FaceGenImages/256_px/"
    OUTPUT_DIR = "Output/"
    DATASET = [INPUT_DATA_DIR + str(line).rstrip() for line in open(DATASET_LIST_PATH,"r")]
    DATASET_SIZE = len(DATASET) 
    MINIBATCH_SIZE = DATASET_SIZE // BATCH_SIZE
```

The output of sample images is only 128x128.

Comment: Looking at the source code, `IMAGE_SIZE` refers to input images. IIUC, output size is hardcoded into the training (check `tf.layers.conv2d`).

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? Convert Nx1024x1024 to Nx256x256 efficiently in regard of both memory and time?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I would like to output samples @256x256px at least, so I can try later 1024x1024. I am aware my IMAGE_SIZE refers to input images. If Output Size is hardcoded into the training, what parameters do I need to change?